# Como trocar de pagina no Ionic V2

Tags: ionic, angular, ionic2

Bom dia galera,
estou com uma duvida, de principiante, que eu criei duas paginas no Ionic v2 porem eu não sei como faco para navegar entre uma e outra. Olhando a documentação do ionic eu vi esse navController adaptei o código que ele deu mas não funcionou.

login.html

```
<ion-footer>
<ion-toolbar>
    <p>Nao e cadastrado? <button ion-button clear (click)="pushPage()">cadastre-se</button>
    </p>
```

login.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, LoadingController,App, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RegisterPage } from '../register/register';
/**
 * Generated class for the LoginPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
  })


export class LoginPage {

  constructor( public navCtrl: NavController,
       public navParams: NavParams,
       public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
       public viewCtrl: ViewController,
       public appCtrl: App) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }

  presentLoading() {
    this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Por favor aguarde...',
      duration: 3000,
      dismissOnPageChange: true
    }).present();
  }

   pushPage() {
     this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
     this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push(RegisterPage);
 }

}
```

ERRO: `Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): navigation stack needs at least one root page`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quiser que a próxima página tenha a opção de voltar no topo da tela, use:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

goToPage() {
   this.navCtrl.push(NoticiaPage);
}
```

Se você quiser deixar a próxima tela como a principal, use:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

goToPage() {
   this.navCtrl.setRoot(SolicitacaoCodigoPage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta isto:

```
pushPage() {
    this.navCtrl.pop();
    this.navCtrl.push(RegisterPage);
}
```

Verifica também se a pagina esta definida no app.module.ts